# java split expression by character but not in a pattern

Tags: java, regex, split

Regex experts, need help with splitting this:

```
((1+2 eq 3) and (2+5 eq 6) or currentyear('yyy') eq '2017')
```

into:

```
1, 2, eq, 3, and, 2, 5, eq, 6, or, currentyear('yyy'), eq, 2017
```

I’m using the regex:

```
"[() ]"
```

Problem is the function expression `currentyear('yyyy')` is also getting split at the brackets.

Comment: Did you actually want to _throw away_ the `+` signs, or is that a typo?

Comment: that was a typo, only thing I wan to ensure is currentYear('yyyy') does not get split into currentYear, 'yyyy'

Comment: Was any of the answers helpful to you?

Comment: what I actually need is

Answer (score 0):

Not bulletproof, but this regex should work:

```
"(?<!')[()](?!')|'\\)| '?$"
```

It uses negative look ahead/behind to *not* split when preceded/followed by `'`/`'`, and adds a split for the trailing `')` and spaces optionally followed by a quote.

Answer (score 0):

This is as good as it gets:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("\\s(?=\\w+\\(.*?\\))|(?:^|\\s)\\(+|\\)$|\\s|\\+|(?<=\\d)\\)",Pattern.MULTILINE);
  String[] parts = re.split(sourcestring);
    for(int partsIdx = 0; partsIdx < parts.length; partsIdx++ ){
      System.out.println( "[" + partsIdx + "] = " + parts[partsIdx]);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[0] = 
[1] = 1
[2] = 2
[3] = eq
[4] = 3
[5] = 
[6] = and
[7] = 2
[8] = 5
[9] = eq
[10] = 6
[11] = 
[12] = or
[13] = currentyear('yyy')
[14] = eq
[15] = '2017'
```

Raw Split Pattern:

```
\s(?=\w+\(.*?\))|(?:^|\s)\(+|\)$|\s|\+|(?<=\d)\)
```

Nonetheless, a parser does a better job.